# Autoindenting Haskell in Vim

Tags: vim, haskell

I started playing with Haskell and I use Vim. 
I have autoindent on in my vimrc, but it seems to not be aware of haskell somehow. I would like to autoindent work in some cases where it doesn't (for example, after = and newline).

How can I customize autoindentation rules in vim? (I googled it, but every site suggested turning autoindent on, which I already had).

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What did you search for? [This](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1968) page is the first result when you search "vim autoindent haskell" in google.

Comment: I searched for "autoindent vim haskell", and this one was not on the first page at all. You may get different results depending on how much google knows about your search habits. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh the irony, I just searched for "haskell indentation vim" and the first match was StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [Haskell mode for Vim](http://projects.haskell.org/haskellmode-vim/).